# Best way to select multiple selections seperatly from foreach output

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, foreach

I have this foreach loop:

```
foreach ($userItems_get as $item => $value) {
    if ($value['prefab'] == 'wearable') {       
        echo $value['name'] . "</br>";
        echo "<img src=\"{$value['image_inventory']}.png\" width=\"90\" height=\"60\">" . "</br>";

        if (!isset($value['item_rarity'])) {
            $rarity = "common";
        } else {
            $rarity = $value['item_rarity'];
        }

        echo $rarity . "</br>";

        foreach ($userItemsLoad as $key => $values) {   
            if ($item == $values['defindex']) {
                echo $values['id'] . "</br></br>";
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

which outputs the data in this format:
http://puu.sh/kVTjk/c1471e903a.jpg

I want the user to select which item he wants to trade/use and i want to recieve the ID of that item which is the integer value at the bottom, the user should be able to select multiple items?

How do i accomplish this? and whats the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Start by adding some structure to your html. Store what is needed in element attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of ways of achieving this.

You can use normal Submit:

```
<form method="POST" action="script.php">

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach ($userItems_get as $item => $value) {
    if ($value['prefab'] == 'wearable') {

        $id = "";
        foreach ($userItemsLoad as $key => $values) {

            if ($item == $values['defindex']) {

                $id = $values['id'];
                break;
            }

        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="itemSelect[]" class="itemSelect" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></td>
            <td>
                <img src="<?php echo $value['image_inventory']; ?>.png" width="90" height="60">
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $value['name']; ?><br />
                <?php
                if (!isset($value['item_rarity'])) {
                    $rarity = "common";
                } else {
                    $rarity = $value['item_rarity'];
                }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    }


}

?>
</table>
    <button type="Submit">
        Normal Submit
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="ajSubmit">
        Ajax Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Script.php:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST['itemSelect']);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Or Use jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#ajSubmit").click(function() {
        var selectedItemIds = $("input.itemSelect").map(function(){
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
    });
});
</script>
```

The `selectedItemIds` will hold all the ID values.

Comment: I'm not really fimiliar with jquery but i want to able to make something like this: http://puu.sh/kVXo0/c1f885af24.jpg here you just click on the items and click a submit button? how do i make the table like that? thanks.

Comment: I am assuming you have the stylesheet and the html with you.

Comment: I dont, i'll try and make it i guess.. dont have alot of experience in html and css! but i'll try and comment back.

Comment: okay i have the html here and heres the fresh loop? can you help me now? Thanks. http://pastebin.com/jPGE8Y7W

Answer (score 0):

Add a checkbox for each items, and add a class for the checkboxes for referencing

```
<input class="itemId" type="checkbox" value="$values['defindex']">
```

You can use `JQuery` to select all the checked checkboxes and loop then in a each loop

```
//Select all input elements which has class of itemId and it is checked then loop through with each.
$("input.itemId[checked='checked']").each(function(){
    var itemId = $(this).val();
    alert(itemId);

    //Do something else

}
```